# Density of this gaussian vector

Tags: probability-theory

If $f(x,y)$ is the density of a gaussian vector with normal distribution $\mathcal{N} \Biggl( \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1  \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 \\ 1 & 2  \end{pmatrix} \Biggr) $ and $g(x,y)$ is the density of gaussian vector $(X, Y)$ where $g(x,y)= C f(x,y) \Bbb{1}_{y\geq 0}$, how can we express $C$ without necessarily calculating it?
Calculating $f(x)$ is relatively straightforward, as $$f(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt 6} \exp\Biggl(-\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} x & y-1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}4 & 1 \\ 1 &2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} x\\y-1\end{pmatrix} \Biggr),$$but I am not sure how to characterize $C$ in any way. By multiplying with the indicator function of $y\geq 0$, I am thinking we need to divide by a probability of $Y$ for the integral of the density to be $1$, but I can't think of the right approach. Thanks for the help!